# How to quit/exit from a subscriber

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey all,
I have two publishers with two topics using rospy. I have a third node that subscribe to each of both topics in sequence. I want to use one subscriber for a specified times (may be 10 or 20) and after that exit from this subscriber. Then I subscribe to second and want it to be automatically stopped after given number of times as above. I scanned the google I came to know subscriber.unregister() but it gives error that "'tuple' has no attribute 'unregister'". Any solution to exit from rospy subscriber automatically with out pressing Crl+C.

```
sb = None 
sb=rospy.Subscriber(topic1,type1,self.callback,(self,sb))
rospy.spin()
sb=rospy.Subscriber(topic2,type2,self.callback,(self,sb))
rospy.spin()

def callback(self,sb):
 self.c = self.c + 1
 if self.c == 10:
    sb.unregister()
```

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56247/how-to-quit/exit-from-a-subscriber/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-02-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-25**:
According to the API that should work. Can you come up with a minimal example to reproduce this.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-02-25**:
sb = None;
sb=rospy.Subscriber(topic1,type1,self.callback,(sb));
rospy.spin();
sb=rospy.Subscriber(topic2,type2,self.callback,(sb);
rospy.spin()
def callback(self,sb):
self.c = self.c + 1;
if self.c == 10:
sb.unregister();

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-26**:
Please update your original post with the code. It's not readable in the comment. As far as I can see, something with the parentheses seems wrong.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-02-26**:
I have included code up, but its mixed with message. Infact code creates a subscriber and call a callback, I want that callback should be closed after few iteration and then next comes. Both subscriber use the same call back function with differe messagetype. I wanna know how to quit callback.thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you're passing the tuple `(self, sb)` as the callback args and this tuple now is passed to the callback function under the name `sb`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-02-27**:
but my question is different. I wanna know how to exit from a callback. unregister does not work in this case, It giver error no attribute as "unregister". Is there any way to exit from a call back after letting it execute for some specified times???? thanks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-27**:
unregister does, what it is supposed to do. The problem is that you are not calling unregister on the subscriber, but on the tuple that you pass in.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-02-27**:
ok then can you please write to me how can I call it on the subscriber? just simple example would be nice. thnx

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-27**:
I think the problem that you are not passing a subscriber, but a tuple with (self, subscriber) to your function.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-02-28**:
Infact in tuple 'self' I need to keep the data in the callback. But I have checked it by removing the tuple then I get error there is no attribute 'unregister'. I would aks you to just write to me the definiton and call of the callback how can I pass only subscriber please? Thanks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-28**:
Given that you are within a class, I'd suggest to use `self.sb = rospy.Subscriber...` not passing any other values and within the callback call `self.sb.unregister()`.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2013-03-05**:
thank you!